# Navigation bar drop down down not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am working with mvc. I tried of creating navigation bar dropdown. I used the following html code to create navigation bar drop down

```
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="menu">
      Report
  <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">a </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">e</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
```

But I got the following output in the UI. I don't know the issue

[image]

I dont know why a and b values are not appearing in the UI. Could anyone help me with this?

This is the css file i am using

```
element.style {
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    border-color: #101010;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container > .navbar-header, .container-fluid > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse, .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.container > .navbar-header, .container-fluid > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse, .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 340px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
.collapse {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
Inherited from 
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from 
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .dl-horizontal dd:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .container:before, .container:after, .container-fluid:before, .container-fluid:after, .row:before, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after, .nav:before, .nav:after, .navbar:before, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:before, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:before, .pager:after, .panel-body:before, .panel-body:after, .modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
.clearfix:after, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .container:after, .container-fluid:after, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after, .nav:after, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:after, .panel-body:after, .modal-footer:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .dl-horizontal dd:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .container:before, .container:after, .container-fluid:before, .container-fluid:after, .row:before, .row:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before, .form-horizontal .form-group:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .btn-toolbar:after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after, .nav:before, .nav:after, .navbar:before, .navbar:after, .navbar-header:before, .navbar-header:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:after, .pager:before, .pager:after, .panel-body:before, .panel-body:after, .modal-footer:before, .modal-footer:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: perhaps they are covered by something else? You might have a padding on `ul` or margin-bottom on `li`... This combined with `z-index` can cause this behaviour. Post you css, so we could see what's up.

Comment: Can you add your css?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/49873qds/1/  I think there are some other css which haven been implemented and are causing this problem. If you could post the `css` parts too , can be a better help .

Comment: Try setting a higher `z-index` to `.dropdown-menu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess, you might need to set the `<ul>` some params:

```css
.dropdown-menu {top: auto; margin-top: 0;}
/* OR */
.dropdown-menu {top: 0; margin-top: 2em;}
/* OR */
.dropdown-menu {z-index: 99;}
```

**Update from Comment:** Try the third option! Could be `z-index` issue.

Comment: @Priya Gotcha! Check out my updated answer. Solution #3.

Comment: @Priya Do you have a live fiddle?

Comment: No @Praveen. I'm not having live fiddle

Comment: @Priya Okay try the Solution #3 and let me know!

Comment: If I use .dropdown-menu {top: 0; margin-top: 2em;},

I'm not able to see c and d
@praveen

Comment: @Priya Nooo! Use the third one. Just `z-index: 99;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80567/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-priya).